# Reference about Relation between Probabilistic Turing Machine and Turing Machine of every hierarchy

Tags: reference-request, computational-complexity, computability-theory

What are the relation between Probabilistic Turing Machine and Turing Machine of every hierarchy, for instance, are the Probabilistic PDA and NPDA equivalent? the Probabilistic LBA and LBA equivalent?etc. please give me the reference which prove those result, thanks in advance.

Comment: Simultaneously cross-posted at https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/46681/reference-about-relation-between-probabilistic-turing-machine-and-turing-machine .

Comment: @EmilJeřábek thank you for your reminding, deleted the one of cstheory